# How to redirect stdin in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, debuggers

When I use IDA, I can use stdin from the file as in bash.

[image]

When I tried to do it in OllyDbg, it processed the parameters simply as a string.

[image]

Can I redirect stdin in OllyDbg?